# R Plumber API validate request matches specification

Tags: r, openapi, plumber

I have created an API with Plumber and also created an OpenAPI specification (or rather, modified the one auto-generated by plumber) that prescribes the format/content of the request body.

I'd like to validate requests to check if they satisfy this specification.

Of course, I could write that validation code myself for this specific API, but that would effectively duplicate the specification, just in another form. Any change in the spec would mean also changing the validation logic. I'd like to avoid that duplication and **validate the request against the OpenAPI Specification directly.**

Minimal example:

```
pr <- plumber::pr_post(pr,
  path = "/example",
  handler = function(req, res) {
    return("Return String")
  }
)
pr <- plumber::pr_set_api_spec(
  pr,
  api = function(spec) {
    spec$paths$`/example`$post$requestBody$content$`application/json`$schema <-
      list(
        type = "object",
        properties = list(
          string_required = list(
            type = "string",
            example = "Hello"
          ),
          string_optional = list(
            type = "string",
            example = "World!"
          )
        ),
        required = list("string_required")
      )
    return(spec)
  }
)
plumber::pr_run(pr)
```

This obviously always returns `"Return String"`, regardless of the request's format. I'd like it to throw an appropriate error-result if `string_required` is missing from the request or something besindes the defined elements is in the request body.

Is there some Plumber function I've missed that does this?
Is there some additional R package that can do it?

Thanks a lot for your answers!